# C++: choosing a `const char *` vs `std::string` when using delegating constructor

Tags: c++, string, stl, overloading, delegating-constructor

Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo (const char *in) {
        printf ("C string constructor called\n");
    }
    Foo (std::string const &in) : Foo(in.c_str()) {
        printf ("C++ string constructor called\n");
    }
};
Foo bar ("I never asked for this");
//C string constructor called
```

So, a constant `string` is treated as a `const char *` one.

But what would change, if we make a `std::string` constructor "primary"?

Can we expect that an `std::string` object would be created and passed to corresponding constructor without calling a C-string related one?

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo (std::string const &in) {
        printf ("C++ string constructor called\n");
    }
    Foo (const char *in) : Foo(std::string (in)) {
        printf ("C string constructor called\n");
    }
};
Foo bar ("I never asked for this");
//C++ string constructor called
//C string constructor called
```

Again, the C-string constructor was called *first*.

Is this behavior described in C++ standard, or is it compiler-related?

Would this work the same way for e.g. templates or overloaded functions?

I compiled with GCC 7.3.0 (MSYS2 x64).

Comment: `But what would change, if we make a std::string constructor "primary"?` What?

Comment: I think "primary" is meant to indicate the constructor that calls the delegate.

Comment: @tkausl Regardless of which constructor delegates to which, `Foo bar("");` will call the `const char*` constructor. Delegation doesn't impact overload resolution.

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward to me, you're passing a `const char*` and it's using the `const char*` constructor in both cases. The `std::string` delegate just gets called immediately in the second case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That could pass for an answer. Especially the _Delegation doesn't impact overload resolution._ part.

Comment: @Ron Maybe, but I'm not actually sure that's what the question is asking. Come to think of it, this question may need to be closed as being unclear.

Comment: not answering your question, but I wouldnt write a `std::string` and a `const char*` for every constructor / method that takes a string, but rather provide only the `string` one and if the user really thinks they need to use `const char*` they can still create a string first (or go for `const char*` only and let the user call `c_str()`)

Comment: @user463035818 That depends. It seems OP is only interested in the `std::string`'s `c_str()`. Having a `const char*` constructor means not having to construct a temporary `std::string` when making a `Foo`. But this example is incomplete as even the `const char*` constructor doesn't care about it's argument. It's hard to see what the intent is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"I never asked for this"` is a [string literal](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#8) which consists of `const char` elements:

```
Foo bar ("I never asked for this"); // calls Foo (const char *in)
```

Thus, `Foo (const char *in)` will always get *selected* by overload resolution **regardless** of the "order" in which you declare your constructors.

As seen in your 2nd example,

```
Foo (const char *in) : Foo(std::string (in))
```

The [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) is selected and will call the *target constructor*, as selected by the only member of the initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as *primary* constructor in C++.

What you observe is that the delegated to constructor (*target constructor*) body is executed first. Then the body of the constructor that delegates (*delegating constructor*).

[Delegating constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor):

> In this case, the *target constructor* is selected by overload resolution and executed first, then the control returns to the *delegating constructor* and its body is executed.

Answer (score 1):

[Overload Resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) and [Constructor Delegation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) are two completely different things that do not influence each other at all.

Overload Resolution avoids implicit conversions when possible.

A string literal like `"I never asked for this"` is a `const char[]`, which decays to `const char *`.  That is an exact match for your `const char *` constructor, so that is the one that gets called.  Calling your `std::string` constructor with a string literal as input would require an implicit conversion, as the compiler would have construct a temporary `std::string` object to bind to the `std::string const &` reference.

Had you written this code instead:

```
Foo bar (std::string("I never asked for this"));
```

Or this:

```
std::string str = "I never asked for this";
Foo bar (str);
```

Then the `std::string const &` constructor would be called instead of the `const char *` constructor, as there is no implicit conversion from `std::string` to `const char *`.

How constructors delegate to each other is an *implementation detail* AFTER the compiler decides *which* constructor to call.